# Keep image same line even small image at last at grid system

Tags: html, css

I am designing a gallery. My current gallery look is as following.[image: This is current look. It flow if the last item is small.]

But I want if the last or second image is small still should not flow like this way.

Actually I want the following style.
[image: My desired style.]

My current html are as follow.

```
<div id="portfolio-items" class="grids portfolio-items">

<div id="portfolio-1" class="grid-4">
    <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="#/1/"></a>
        <figcaption>
            <h4>Qui modi aut et</h4>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" class="button">Details</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div id="portfolio-2" class="grid-4">
    <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="#/2/"></a>
        <figcaption>
            <h4>Qui modi aut et</h4>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" class="button">Details</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div id="portfolio-3" class="grid-4">
    <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/"></a>
        <br>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <figcaption>
            <h4>Qui modi aut et</h4>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" class="button">Details</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div id="portfolio-3" class="grid-4">
    <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="#/1/"></a>
        <figcaption>
            <h4>Qui modi aut et</h4>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" class="button">Details</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div id="portfolio-3" class="grid-4">
    <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="#/1/"></a>
        <figcaption>
            <h4>Qui modi aut et</h4>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" class="button">Details</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div id="portfolio-3" class="grid-4">
    <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="#/2/"></a>
        <figcaption>
            <h4>Qui modi aut et</h4>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" class="button">Details</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div id="portfolio-3" class="grid-4">
    <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="#/1/"></a>
        <figcaption>
            <h4>Qui modi aut et</h4>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" class="button">Details</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div id="portfolio-3" class="grid-4">
    <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="#/1/"></a>
        <figcaption>
            <h4>Qui modi aut et</h4>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" class="button">Details</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div id="portfolio-3" class="grid-4">
    <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="#/2/"></a>
        <figcaption>
            <h4>Qui modi aut et</h4>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" class="button">Details</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<div id="portfolio-3" class="grid-4">
    <figure>
        <a href="#"><img src="#/1/"></a>
        <figcaption>
            <h4>Qui modi aut et</h4>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" class="button">Details</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

and my css are as following.

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.grids {
zoom: 1;
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;
}
.grids:before, .grids:after {
display: table;
content: "";
}
.grids:after {
clear: both;
}
.grids [class*="grid-"] {
float: left;
padding: 15px;
vertical-align: top;
}

.grid-1 {
width: 8.33333333%;
}

.grid-2 {
width: 16.66666667%;
}

.grid-3 {
width: 25%;
}

.grid-4 {
width: 33.33333333%;
}

.grid-5 {
width: 41.66666667%;
}

.grid-6 {
width: 50%;
}

.grid-7 {
width: 58.33333333%;
}

.grid-8 {
width: 66.66666667%;
}

.grid-9 {
width: 75%;
}

.grid-10 {
width: 83.33333333%;
}

.grid-11 {
width: 91.66666667%;
}

.grid-12 {
width: 100%;
}
}
.portfolio-items {
font-size: 18px;
font-size: 1.125rem;
}
.portfolio-items *:not(a) {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.portfolio-items figure {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
.portfolio-items figure:hover figcaption {
opacity: 1;
-ms-transform: translateY(0px);
-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
transform: translateY(0px);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
}
.portfolio-items figure:hover img {
-ms-transform: translateY(-50px);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
transform: translateY(-50px);
}
.portfolio-items figcaption {
position: absolute;
background-color: #363f48;
display: block;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
padding: 17px 20px;
text-align: center;
opacity: 0;
-ms-transform: translateY(100%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
transform: translateY(100%);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
}
.portfolio-items img {
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
transition: transform 0.4s;
}
.portfolio-items h4 {
font-size: inherit;
color: white;
margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
.portfolio-items .button {
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 1;
padding: 8px 33px;
background-color: #4CC1BE;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Which styling layout you are using, try to find a ```row``` type like in bootstrap styling?

Comment: can you add working fiddle

Comment: @sayful, Just remove all <br> tag and check is that same as you want?

Comment: Min-height will do the work. but I couldn't see the images flow in your gallery. I just tried to put all images in it. Check and provide a fiddle with this codepen.http://codepen.io/shivk/pen/pRzqLw

Answer (score 0):

i think your images have different height. You can simply fix this with `min-height`

```
.grid-4 figure {
   min-height:250px; /* what ever you want */
   max-height:250px; /* what ever you want */
}
```

Comment: min-height works if I know the max height. But it will not work if image exceed the min height.

Comment: then keep both min and max height limits with class img-responsive.

Comment: @sayful no problem add max-height too

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding` in below css rules.

```
.grids [class*="grid-"]{
   padding:0;
}
```

Another way to change below calss css rules.

```
.grids {
   zoom: 1;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-right: 15px;
}

.grids [class*="grid-"] {
   float: left;
   margin: -15px;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Also set

```
.grid-4 figure{
  max-height:250px;
}
```

Comment: padding: 0; does not fix the problem.

Comment: It removes padding between images. also does not fix the problem.

Comment: Please set image max-height.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..consider this if suits you... I just cleared float value for every third image.

```
            .grids .grid-4:nth-child(3n+3){
             clear:both;
            }
```

Comment: It brings the image to next line.

Answer (score 0):

set `min-height` for `.grid-4` class for example

```
.grid-4 figure{
  min-height:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding css3 flexbox.

```
.grids {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Though I know flexbox does not support at all browser specially IE prior to 11.